# number of periods (custom) between two dates

Tags: java

I want to find out how many periods (custom) are there between two dates. Like how many weeks are between 1 july to 2nd Aug or how many half months are there between 2 nd Juy and 14 Dec, where in half month would be customizable whether it ends on 15th or 16th.

IS there any library where this or something similar has been done? Not that its tricky but just want to know if such things exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Joda Time is great but it doesn't have direct support for your needs, although it represents the concepts you want to handle

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html

In particular, see http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_period.html

and the methods .dividedBy(int) and .multipliedBy(int)